# Return a pointer to 2D array from a function - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

So what I am trying to achieve is to return a pointer to a 2D array from the function so it could accessed in main(). I know there are some C++ libraries that does it for you like `std::vector` but I am trying to avoid dynamic memory allocation since I am working on embedded board (STM32) so I will stick to just normal pointers and arrays. (**ALSO for some reason I can't use `std::array` in KEIL uVision, which is also why I am forced to work with pointers/arrays**)

In addition, I understand that returning a pointer to a local array `int arr[2][2]` defined inside the function is not a good idea since it will no longer be valid after the function returns, which is why I creating `test_array`, declaring it inside a class and defining it in a function (acting as a global variable) so I assume this shouldn't be a problem. What do you guys think? However, doing it this way gives an error **"Excess elements in scalar initializer"**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file.hpp"

int main() {

  myClass class_object;

  class_object.value = class_object.foo();


}
```

---

```
//file.hpp

#include <stdio.h>

class myClass{

  int array[2][2];
  int (*foo())[2];
  int (*value)[2];

  int test_array[2][2];   //declaring here! 

};
```

---

```
//file.cpp 

#include "file.hpp" 

int (*myClass::foo())[2]{

    test_array[2][2]={ {10,20}, {30, 40} }; //defining here - ERROR!!

    int arr[2][2]= {
        {1, 10},
        {20, 30}
    };


return arr;


}
```

Comment: `int (*myClass::foo())[2]{` is this some new way of doing function declarations that I haven't caught up with yet? It looks like gobbledegook! Also you are still returning the local which you said you knew not to do. Finally, how about telling us where the error occurred?

Comment: Why are people so obsessed with C arrays? :(

Comment: @Baum Because incompetent profs are teaching them these are _important_, Industry could save a load of money by just getting rid of these people.

Comment: `test_array[2][2]` is an invalid access past the end of the member array, not a name for the array.  And you can't assign an array.  If you used `std::array<std::array<int,2>,2>`, you might have fewer problems.

Comment: Please please please use `std::array`

Comment: @John3136 It's a valid syntax for a member function which returns a pointer to array.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for clarifying. I still say it looks like gobbledegook though ;-)

Comment: @TristanBrindle `std::array` for some reason isn't recognized in keil (program that I am using for C++ embed dev)

Comment: @aschepler I thought `[2][2]` was defining the total size of the array i.e rows and columns. And then in function I am initializing it.

Comment: @John3136 check the code - I have left a comment on the line where the error occurred!

Comment: Off topic: If I'm reading this right, returning `arr`, an automatic variable scoped by the function, is going to end in badness. `arr` will be invalid memory before the caller gets a chance to do anything with it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen it's the simplest way how to work with raw memory in C and C++. So I love to use arrays, when I'm too lazy to write the assembly directly. Then again I'm completely baffled what are two dimensional arrays, and what they are good for... must be some high level abstraction complication, makes me always wonder why people don't stick to the simple code, but they still invent new ways how to make it more hidden and complex, where few trivial machine codes would do the same thing.

Comment: @Ped7g *"it's the simplest way how to work with raw memory in C and C++."* Evidently not, at least for C++, as questions from people getting it wrong demonstrate several times every single day. You being "baffled" by an array of arrays is even more prove.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm used to see hordes of people on SO not having any clue about how CPU works and how computer memory is used... doesn't mean it's difficult, it's simple stuff, zeros and ones. BTW, two dimensional C array is not array of arrays. The C N-dim arrays are basically just single dimension arrays with syntax sugar of letting the compiler write the offset calculation for you... useless, as it's super difficult to maintain the type (decays to ordinary ptr in a blink of eye), and easy to calc offset manually. Array of arrays is something different for me (array of pointers).

Comment: @Ped7g No, it *is* an array of arrays, and an array of pointers is an array of pointers, not an array of arrays. A pointer is not an array, an array is not a pointer, same holds for arrays of said objects.

Comment: @Ped7g Also, regarding *"useless, as it's super difficult to maintain the type"*: This only holds for C arrays, not for `std::array`, which is exactly my point.

Comment: `int x[2][2];` is just a pointer which wants to be something more, but fails hard at first occasion. If you treat it like a pointer since the start, usually it saves you more troubles, than it creates. Also the memory is just 1 dimensional array, so again by masking it through the [][] notation you usually gain very little, for example to clear a matrix you then must write two nested loops instead of setting up just M\*N elements of matrix array. There were some very good reasons, why `std::array` was introduced in C++11, that's strong typing, and I can adore that. But C arrays are *meh* ...

Comment: @Ped7g Alright, now I can no longer tell whether you are agreeing or disagreeing with me... If you feel like this needs further discussion, please start a room.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem:

```
test_array[2][2]={ {10,20}, {30, 40} }; //defining here - ERROR!!
```

is not defining. `test_array` was defined up in `myClass`. This is attempting to assign to a single element of `test_array`, specifically `[2][2]` which does not exist. What particularly offends the compiler is not the out of bounds access, but that `={ {10,20}, {30, 40} };` is trying to stuff an array into a single array element. The compiler is expecting a single number, so four numbers is definitely in excess.

Unfortunately I don't know of a good way to do what you want to do. You can initialize an array with an initializer list, but you can't assign from one.

So

```
class myClass{
public:

    myClass();
    void foo();

    int test_array[2][2];   //declaring here!
};

// you can do this:
myClass::myClass(): test_array{ {10,20}, {30, 40} }
{

}

void myClass::foo()
{
    // but you can't do this:
    test_array = { {10,20}, {30, 40} };
}
```

Depending on what you do with `test_array`, initializing in the constructor may work for you. If you have to reset the array on every call to `foo`, perhaps an Automatic variable is a better fit for you

```
void myClass::foo()
{
    int temp_array[2][2] = { {10,20}, {30, 40} };

    // use temp_array

    // maybe copy temp_array to test_array with good ol' memcpy here if you 
    // need to carry the state for some reason.
}
```

To silence the elephant in the room [and gain access to `std::array`, give this a try.](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3696.htm) Note: I've never done this. It could be an utter freaking disaster for all I know, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to work with C-Array, use typedef to have *normal* syntax:

```
class myClass{
    public:
    using array2 = int[2][2];

    myClass() {
        test_array[0][0] = 0;
        test_array[0][1] = 1;
        test_array[1][0] = 2;
        test_array[1][1] = 3;
    }

    const array2& getArray() const { return test_array; }
    array2& getArray() { return test_array; }

private:
    array2 test_array;
};
```

Comment: I don't know this seems a bit perplexed. Plus I don't want to initialize an array inside a class but inside a function as I am implementing some mathematical functions inside it

Comment: @Doej if this is embedded platform with tight constraints, it's questionable why don't you remove dynamic memory completely, why don't you have reserved global memory for all possible results (let's say you **know** the app will produce at most 100 of 2x2 int arrays, so just have the 1600 bytes of memory for results fixed at compile time as a global, and give the function target pointer where it should do its calculation,  instead of returning something as impractical as pointer to C array (which usually quickly decays to ordinary `int*`, losing any advantage of starting as array type).